# Paraphrase of "A big part of the secret...."

Tags: paraphrasing

[image: A picture of the quoted text]

> A big part of the secret is an extensive and expensive network of sporting academic underpinned by science and medicine. [Source](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Sample_Reading_13_Passage_1.htm)

I don't understand the part of "sporting academic underpinned by science and medicine." Please help me to paraphrase this sentence.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are after is not a *paraphrase* of the sentence, but an *explanation* of it. Hopefully, medica's editing of your question to match the source text will now have resolved your query. (Incidentally, note the second R in the spelling of 'paraphrase'.)

Comment: *Underpin*: to prop up or support from below; strengthen. The sentence states Australians are winners because there is support for sporting academies - sports training institutions - which themselves use medicine and science in their training techniques.

Comment: It is academic in this sentence. I don't understand what"academic"means in this sentence. none or adjective?

Comment: @Kris - the error is there. The source sentence is the third in the first paragraph. In context it does make sence that it's academic. But that is not the original sentence, which makes more sense.

Comment: Zelia, please recheck your sentence (I have, from several sources, including the test); if it is written *academics*, it is in error. See the source I linked to. Read the first paragraph; it is the third sentence. Please see my second comment. Is it clearer now?

Comment: *Academic* refers to (the body of work, body of knowledge,) mainly the people involved, in the field of study related to sporting. This is being supported by those in the fields of science and medicine. Sport these days is highly scientific.

Comment: @medica What's it with the references? The image does not match with the "Source" content.

Comment: @Kris - these test booklets take their material from press releases, etc. They (the test booklet makers) made three mistakes in that paragraph alone. *That's* what is "with the references". I shouldn't even need to explain this to an English speaking high rep user of this site.

Answer (score 4):

[*AUSTRALIA'S SPORTING SUCCESS*](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Sample_Reading_13_Passage_1.htm)

> They play hard, they play often, and they play to win. Australian sports teams win more than their fair share of titles, demolishing rivals with [**seeming**](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Sample_Reading_13_Passage_1.htm)  ease. How do they do it? [**A big part of the secret is an extensive and expensive network of sporting *academies* underpinned by science and medicine**](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Sample_Reading_13_Passage_1.htm) . At the Australian Institute of Sport (AIS), hundreds of youngsters and pros live and train under the eyes of coaches. Another body, the Australian Sports Commission (ASC), finances [**programmes**](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Sample_Reading_13_Passage_1.htm) of excellence in a total of 96 sports for thousands of sportsmen and women. Both provide intensive coaching, training facilities and nutritional advice.

The test booklet is in error, misspelling **words** from its source (above). What on earth is *with meeting ease**? It's **seeming** ease.

In any case, the sentence states Australians are winners because there is great support for **sporting academies** - *sports training institutions* - which themselves use medicine and science in their training techniques. It's a big business with a lot of money, science and medicine behind it.

Comment: +1 I wonder how many questions come here from such badly done copies of what was perfectly good English.

Comment: @Frank - good question. From what I've seen so far (I've been here 6 months), it's not terribly infrequent.